# Can I write my own will, or do I need a lawyer to draw one up for me?

Tags: estate-planning

I've seen software packages at Office Depot and such, and am considering using one.  What are some pros/cons?

Comment: *Great* question.  I wish we had some lawyers on board for an opinion on this one!

Answer (score 6):

IANAL, nor do I play one on TV.

I have listened to lawyers on this topic, on radio shows, and the consensus seemed to be that the software packages are good for simple needs, and are certainly better than nothing.

While you are at it, don't forget the power(s) of attorney!  You should likely have both medical and financial set up, software can help, or the same lawyer for your will can draw those up as well.

The key points in writing a will are the same, if you use a lawyer or not, just a few are listed below, your lawyer or software will walk you through all these and more:

- who is your executor?  That person may be in for some work, particularly if you have complex arrangements that need to be unwound
- who are your beneficiaries?  Generally for a married couple (either in law or common-law) this would be your partner for 100%.  If both of you die together, how is it split among children, if any?
- Do you need trustees or guardians for children?
- you should have a mutual disaster clause.  My wife and I, if we die along with all our kids, have four charities that get the lot.

Comment: +1 even though it took me a while to figure out what "IANAL" meant :)  These are excellent points. Thank you!

Comment: Also: in the United States, your will MUST have witnesses to be valid. The witnesses will be asked to testify at probate court as to the will's authenticity.